# You have an error in your SQL syntax (CREATE PROCEDURE)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to create function in mariadb (latest stable). Want to get all data by company id (int)

```
CREATE FUNCTION getByCompId (cid INT)
RETURN (SELECT * FROM companies WHERE id=cid);
```

end when i try to create, i get error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=111) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN (SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE id=cid)' at line 2
```

Comment: Function may return one scalar value (not multi-column rowset). And function's returning datatype must be specified explicitly (RETURNS attribute). Study carefully: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a tabular resultset from a function, only scalar values. Instead, you can use a stored procedure:

```
delimiter //
create procedure getbycompid (cid int)
begin
    select * from companies where id = cid;
end //
delimiter ;
```

And then you call the procedure like so:

```
call getbycompid(1);
```

Since we have a one-liner, we could shorten the code as just:

```
create procedure getbycompid (cid int)
    select * from companies where id = cid
;
```

Comment: ok, so, if i want to get company name(cname) from table i try:

Comment: ok, so, if i want to get company name(cname) from table i try: CREATE FUNCTION getByCompId (cid INT)
RETURN (SELECT cname FROM companies WHERE id=cid); and have error  right syntax to use near 'RETURN